# While adding <provider> to Persistance.xml it' showing "Invalid content was found starting with element 'provider'."

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I am trying to add  to my persistance.xml file.

Like Below:

```
<provider>oracle.toplink.essentials.PersistenceProvider</provider>
```

When I added to my persistance.xml it's showing

```
Invalid content was found starting with element 'provider'
```

How can I overcome this
I have added 2 jars

```
1.eclipselink.jar
2.javax.persistence_2.0.4.v201112200901.jar
```

Comment: but you don't tell us what your persistence.xml looks like ...

Comment: Have you checked that `<provider>` element is actually the first element in the `<persistence-unit>`? (it must be after the `<description>` element, in case you have one)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
```

With this pom.xml

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
<artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
<version>2.5.0</version>
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you're looking at older version of persistence.xml definition. The `<provider>` element is no longer valid on the java ee 6, check [the persistence.xml xsd](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/javaee/javaee_6.xsd).

So try either using the latest persistence.xml schema or downgrading your java ee environment.

Comment: What do you think the "JavaEE6 XSD" got to do with persistence.xml? Nothing; its for a different file. The real persistence.xml XSD is at http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd